# What is the best view for a displaying an images in android?

Tags: android, android-image

I'm designing an app that splits an image into a 3 x 3 grid. What is the best way to display this image.

Also, How can I move this piece from one point to another on the view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)?  I don't understand your second question.  If you are talking about trying to show the 3x3 grid, use a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html).

You can mess around with the [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) and [image matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageMatrix%28android.graphics.Matrix%29) to change what part of an image is displayed.